# Как это - за что? Простое предложение или сложное? И какой знак внутри - тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как это - за что? Это простое ли сложное предложение? И какой знак нужен - тире или запятая?

Answer (score 1):

***Как это — за что?***

Данное предложение — **неполная разговорная конструкция**, часть диалога, которая восстанавливается по контексту.

В полном виде это выглядит  примерно так: *Кам можно понять **этот вопрос** — за что?*

Это **простое** предложение, в котором с помощью тире обособлена **присоединительная конструкция** со значением раскрытия содержания (повтор заданного вопроса).

Запятой здесь недостаточно, так как надо обозначить паузу, определяющую структуру неполного предложения.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я примерно так и думала, только не знала, как объяснить это тире.